# flutter/dart:: field does not exist

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a bad state error, field does not exist within document....
it says that the field does not exist in the database, but it does (see error)
the logs point to line 100, which is an id of a error, but that appears to be in the database so I am confused as to what the meaning of the error is

video of error: https://youtu.be/CO1Ak6c0B3g

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ijob_clone_app/Widgtes/all_companies_widget.dart';
import '../Widgtes/bottom_nav_bar.dart';

class AllWorkerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AllWorkerScreen> createState() => _AllWorkerScreenState();
}

class _AllWorkerScreenState extends State<AllWorkerScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _searchQueryController = TextEditingController();
  String searchQuery = 'Search query';

  Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return TextField(
      controller: _searchQueryController,
      autocorrect: true,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search for jobs...',
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
      onChanged: (query) => updateSearchQuery(query),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildActions() {
    return <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          _clearSearchQuery();
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  void _clearSearchQuery() {
    setState(() {
      _searchQueryController.clear();
      updateSearchQuery('');
    });
  }

  void updateSearchQuery(String newQuery) {
    setState(() {
      searchQuery = newQuery;
      print(searchQuery);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Colors.deepOrange.shade300, Colors.blueAccent],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          stops: const [0.2, 0.9],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarForApp(indexNum: 1),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.deepOrange.shade300, Colors.blueAccent],
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                stops: const [0.2, 0.9],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: _buildSearchField(),
          actions: _buildActions(),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('jobs')
              .where('jobTitle', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchQuery)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return AllWorkersWidget(
                      userId: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['id'],
                      userName: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['name'],
                      userEmail: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['email'],
                      phoneNumber: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['phoneNumber'],
                      userImageUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['userImageUrl'],
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'There is not users',
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
            return const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Something went wrong',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error log::

```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Reloaded 1 of 1430 libraries in 197ms (compile: 17 ms, reload: 92 ms, reassemble: 71 ms).

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[]
#5      _AllWorkerScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
#6      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build
#7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build
#8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure>
#9      BuildOwner.buildScope
#10     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild
#11     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure>
#12     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure>
#13     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees
#14     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback
#15     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild
#16     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild
#17     RenderSliverList.performLayout
#18     RenderObject.layout
#19     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
#20     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
#21     RenderObject.layout
#22     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
#23     RenderViewport._attemptLayout
#24     RenderViewport.performLayout
#25     RenderObject.layout
#26     RenderBox.layout
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#28     RenderObject.layout
#29     RenderBox.layout
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#31     RenderObject.layout
#32     RenderBox.layout
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#34     RenderObject.layout
#35     RenderBox.layout
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#37     RenderObject.layout
#38     RenderBox.layout
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#40     RenderObject.layout
#41     RenderBox.layout
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#43     RenderObject.layout
#44     RenderBox.layout
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#46     RenderObject.layout
#47     RenderBox.layout
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#49     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#50     RenderObject.layout
#51     RenderBox.layout
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#53     RenderObject.layout
#54     RenderBox.layout
#55     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#56     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#57     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#58     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#59     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#60     PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#61     RendererBinding.drawFrame
#62     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#63     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#64     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#65     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#66     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#67     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#68     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#69     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/EGL_emulation( 4570): app_time_stats: avg=509.85ms min=12.08ms max=7863.23ms count=16
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you are fine,

I think the problem is with your `firebase query` as mentioned above, you are trying to get into `jobs collection` but it seems it doesn't have fields named ("id, name, phone number, etc...") all of these are exist in `users collection` fields, but not `jobs collection`, so it couldn't find it and throwed an error.

hope I could help, have a nice day :)